# Find search term in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do you search for a term in multiple columns: `title`,`content`. For example:

```
$searchTerm = 'android';

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` OR `content` contains $SearchTerm
```

Comment: you can consider using full-text search for searching in multiple columns. that would be fast.http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: @Pushpesh `The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE
   `title` LIKE '%android%'
OR `content` LIKE '%android%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  posts
WHERE
  lower(`title`) LIKE '%android%'
  OR lower(`content`) LIKE '%android%'
```

Comment: does this mean lettercase is not ignored?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` LIKE '%$SearchTerm%' OR `content` LIKE '%$SearchTerm%'";
```