# Query which searches in multiple columns for filter string

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpql

Using Postgresql and Spring.
The Backend gets User Input from the frontend which is called "filter". I want the database "contacts" to be checked in multiple columns:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Contacts c " +
            "WHERE LOWER(CAST(c.supplierNo AS string)) LIKE %:filter% OR LOWER(c.firstName) LIKE    %:filter%" +
            "OR LOWER(c.lastName) LIKE %:filter% OR LOWER(c.supplierName) LIKE %:filter%")
    List<Contacts> findByFilter(String filter);
```

This works for single-word-filters. But I would want the user to enter for example: "John Smith"(firstName SPACE lastName), or maybe Smith Foodmarket(lastName SPACE supplierName) or Foodmarket Smith. You get the idea. How would I go about this?

WHAT I TRIED:

1
[Find search term in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071867/find-search-term-in-multiple-columns)
This  is not it, since I want to be able to search in multiple cols at once.

2
[Search Single Value In Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684531/search-single-value-in-multiple-columns)
I tried this like shown:

```
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Contacts c " +
            "WHERE LOWER(CAST(c.supplierNo AS string)) LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%') OR LOWER(c.firstName) LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%')" +
            "OR LOWER(c.lastName) LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%') OR LOWER(c.supplierName) LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%')")
    List<Contacts> findByFilter(String filter);
```

It is entirely possible that I translated sql -> jpql the wrong way, but this solution does not work as intended

3
Multiple permutations of this, but to no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that if you pass string which contain more than 1 word then all of your conditions will return FALSE

```
SELECT 'JOHN' LIKE '%JOHN DOE%'; -- FALSE
SELECT 'JOHN' LIKE '%JOHN%'; -- TRUE
```

try this

```
SELECT distinct c.*
FROM Contacts c, unnest(array[c.firstName, c.supplierNo, ...more columns]) key
    INNER JOIN unnest(string_to_array(':filter', ' ')) f ON key LIKE '%' || f || '%';
```

SQL code that i tested

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(col1 text, col2 text, col3 text);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('HELLO', 'WORLD', 'TEST');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('FOO', 'BAR', 'DOG');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('CAT', 'FISH', 'PARROT');

SELECT distinct c.*
FROM mytable c, unnest(array[c.col1, c.col2, c.col3]) key
    INNER JOIN unnest(string_to_array('HELLO PARROT', ' ')) f ON key LIKE '%' || f || '%';
```

Comment: it is entirely possible that i made a mistake, converting your sql code into jpql, but as it stands, it didnt work. Could you provide this as jpql?

Comment: @meralex it didnt return any rows or throws exception ? i am not familiar with jpql i provided sql code that i tested before posting answer

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your query for 2 words case.

If filter contains 1 word:
filter1=word
filter2=word

If filter contains 2 words:
filter1=word1
filter2=word2

Updated query

```
@Query(
    "SELECT c FROM Contacts c " +
    "WHERE LOWER(CAST(c.supplierNo AS string)) LIKE %:filter% "
    +" OR LOWER(c.firstName) LIKE    %:filter1%"
    +" OR LOWER(c.lastName) LIKE %:filter2% "
    +" OR LOWER(c.supplierName) LIKE %:filter%"
      )
    List<Contacts> findByFilter(String filter);
```

Comment: Shouldnt there be a part, where filter1 and filter2 are defined? If used like this, it does not even build

Comment: ``filter1`` and ``filter2`` can be defined with ``filter`` in java ``String[] words = filter.split(" ");`` filter1=words[0].  If size of words greater than 1  filter2=words[1] else  filter2=words[0]